# Token Authentication and XSRF / XSS protection

Tags: angularjs, security, authentication, token

I have been reading up on token authentication and the possibility of XSRF and XSS attacks to gain authentication information.

I understand that to prevent XSRF attacks, it is a popular approach to read a custom authentication token from a cookie and then add it to a custom request header before making any AJAX requests. The server can then run validation on the request header rather than on the cookie. I believe AngularJS uses this approach: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

My confusion comes when preventing XSS attacks. Obviously it is best to ensure that no user input is able to inject javascript but lets say a flaw is found, as the cookie mentioned above needs to be read in order to set it's value in the request header, isn't it vulnerable to XSS attacks? As the cookie can not be set to HTTP only, can an attacker not read the cookie to get the authentication token and then forge a request? If so, how can this be prevented?

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, seeing Angular's XSRF protection needs a cookie with the `httpOnly` tag set to `false`. Apparently, if your site is vulnerable to XSS attacks, you can't prevent the attacker from forging a malicious request, even with an XSRF protection. See: https://www.optiv.com/blog/bypassing-csrf-tokens-via-xss

Answer (score 1):

The cookie will only be vulnerable to XSS attacks if your site is vulnerable to XSS attacks.

So you will have to ensure that any user input is sanitised before being displayed on the page.